# Cloning objects that extend other objects (JAVA)

Tags: java, object, minecraft, bukkit

I am trying to make clone an object that extends another object. Here's a bit of background for you.

I'm making a game system and each game is it's own object that extends another object/class called "Arena. For example Capture the Flag extends Arena. Arena has a bunch of variables that need to be unique to the current object. I have a hashmap full of these Games and when needed, the specific Game from the hashmap needs to be cloned. However, when I do use the Java clone() method, it does copy the object that extends Arena but it doesn't copy the class Arena. If that makes sense.So basically if I try doing 2 different games, (Ex: Capture the Flag and Paintball), they both share the same stuff from the Arena class. (Arena is not static) That's not what I need. Is there a way to copy the object and the object it extends?

Comment: Sorry, your description is unintelligible to me. "does copy the object that extends Arena but doesn't copy Arena" - what does it even mean?
Consider writing a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates what you actually want. As minimal as possible. With simple classes, without forcing us to think in terms of Arena or Capture the Flag or Paintball.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you don't have called `super.clone()` somewhere.

Take care to follow and understand all instructions listed in the *clone* method: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#clone()

- Your classes implements *Cloneable*
- In your *clone* methods, always start with `super.clone()` and use that result. You'll probably need to cast it to your class.
- Change the values that need to be unique. Clones all references (fields with non-primitive types) that should be independent (all in case of doubt...).